Deep dive into learning about Matriarchs?
I would like to learn more about the Imahot. I am happy to hear about books written focussing on this topic, gathering sources and summarising them into some easy reading, as well as hear any list of good sources or other works that one would recommend for someone wishing to learn more about his holy Imas.
